# Finding design matrix $X$ in the linear model

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, systems-of-equations, linear-regression

> $y=Xb+e$ is a (General) linear model with $n=p=3$. Given that $b_3$ is non estimable, and $b_1+ 2b_2 + 2b_3$ is estimable. How can I find an $X$ which is consistent with the above?

I think I have a partial solution to it but I do not understand the methodology of solving it.

**My questions**

**1)** How can we show/prove that   $\lambda_1\notin  C(X^T)$ but  $\lambda_2 \in  C(X^T)$?

and lastly,

**2)** How does the design matrix $X$ looks and why ?

So I know

$$b = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\ 
b_2\\
b_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now since $b_3$ is non estimable : $b_3 = λ_1^T b$

$\lambda_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ and   $\lambda_1\notin C(X^T)$ (the column space of $X^T$).

and since $b_1 +2b_2 + 2b_3$ is estimable then $$b_1 +2b_2 + 2b_3 = \lambda_2^T b$$

$\lambda_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\
2
\end{bmatrix}$ and   $\lambda_2$ is  in $C(X^T)$.

We know probably that $X$ is not full column rank.

I was thinking to use $X^T b = \lambda_1$ , $X^T b = \lambda_2 $ to find $X$ matrix but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Any tip ? please?

Comment: Try posting it on cross validated